# Why is the CC sampling+ license incompatible with other CC licenses?

Tags: creative-commons, license-compatibility

Creative Commons used to publish a license called ["Sampling Plus"](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/sampling+/1.0/), but according to [this page](http://creativecommons.org/retiredlicenses), it was retired/deprecated in 2011 due to inadequate demand and **"Not compatible with any other CC license"**.

Why was this license incompatible with the other CC licenses?

According to the [human-readable summary page](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/sampling+/1.0/), the license permits:

- Creative transformations for commercial and non-commercial uses
- Verbatim uses for non-commercial uses

With the condition that:

- You attribute in the manner specified by the author/licensor

At a glance, the freedoms are a mix of NC/ND and the condition is BY. Why is this incompatible with any other CC license? What specific use cases cause it to be incompatible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Sampling+ license effectively prohibits whole-work derivatives (you can't take a Sampling+ work and incorporate it intact into another work, except in very limited circumstances).  This means the license is only partially compatible with the "mainstream licenses" (BY, BY-SA, BY-ND, BY-NC, BY-NC-SA, and BY-NC-ND) -- you need to be careful about *how* you use the Sampling+ content in the combined work.

Going the other direction:

- You can't incorporate ShareAlike-licensed content into a Sampling+ work: it introduces an impermissible license restriction to the SA work (incompatible with BY-SA and BY-NC-SA).
- You can't incorporate NonCommercial content into a Sampling+ work because the Sampling+ license permits commercial use of derivatives (incompatible with BY-NC and BY-NC-SA).
- You can't incorporate No-Derivatives content in a Sampling+ work for obvious reasons (incompatible with BY-ND and BY-NC-ND).

This leave only one possible way of freely combining a "mainstream license" work with a Sampling+ work: incorporating a CC-BY work into a Sampling+ work.  Everything else is restricted or forbidden.

Comment: According to [this](https://creativecommons.org/weblog/entry/7145), Sampling+ is incompatible with even CC-BY; is this accurate?

Comment: @congusbongus, if I'm reading it correctly, they're saying that you can use CC-BY in a Sampling+ work, but you can't use Sampling+ in a CC-BY work.